# How does Integer Division work in python?

Tags: python

So, I have recently heard of Integer Division and that it is very fast. I have always been using Bit Shifting when I do floor(x / 2^n).

So, I have tested if which is faster Integer Division or Bit Shifting so, I made this code where it tests and compare it 100 times and find the mean:

```
    import timeit
    import statistics as stat
    
    def compare_times(a, b):
        res_a = timeit.timeit(a)
        res_b = timeit.timeit(b)
        c = res_a - res_b # if negative, a is faster 
        return c
    
    output = []
    
    for _ in range(100):
        output.append(compare_times("5 >> 1", "5 // 2"))
    
    print (stat.mean(output))
```

And the result is positive, meaning b is faster. Isn't bit shifting working directly at the bit of the number? Why is it slower than Integer Division?

I tested another thing to see if it is because I chose 5, so:

```
    import timeit
    import statistics as stat
    import random
    
    def compare_times(a, b):
        res_a = timeit.timeit(a)
        res_b = timeit.timeit(b)
        c = res_a - res_b # if negative, a is faster 
        return c
    
    output = []
    
    for _ in range(100):
        number = random.randrange(5000, 50001)
        output.append(compare_times(f"{number} >> 1", f"{number} // 2"))
    
    print (stat.mean(output))
```

which also outputted positve.

The only time I see a (bit shift) is faster than Integer Division is when in floor(x / 2^n), n >= 2.

So, ultimately, how does Integer Division work? And why is it faster than Bit Shift in terms of smaller numbers?

Comment: You'd want to look at the bytecode output for those expressions to know for sure.  Since you're using constants there could be optimizations applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time difference you're seeing is spurious; in fact, `5 // 2` and `5 >> 1` both compile to the same CPython bytecode:

```py
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis('5 // 2')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis('5 >> 1')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

That is, the computation is done at compile-time, not at runtime, so you are actually just measuring how long it takes to load a pre-computed constant in both cases. To get an accurate benchmark, you need to actually perform the computation at runtime, such as by passing a variable; I also suggest using larger numbers (or raising the number of repetitions beyond the default of 1,000,000) to get a more reliable comparison.

```py
>>> n = 1234 ** 56 # a 174-digit number
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda: n // 2)
0.32904140199389076
>>> timeit(lambda: n >> 1)
0.12879745499958517
```

So we can see that at least for very large numbers, bit-shifting is faster, as you would expect. For smaller numbers there may be no significant difference.

As for how CPython actually computes integer division, the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/145bf269df3530176f6ebeab1324890ef7070bf8/Objects/longobject.c#L2596) is freely available to read, and according to a comment there, the algorithm used is found in a well-known textbook:

```c
    /* We follow Knuth [The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 2 (3rd
       edn.), section 4.3.1, Algorithm D], except that we don't explicitly
       handle the special case when the initial estimate q for a quotient
       digit is >= PyLong_BASE: the max value for q is PyLong_BASE+1, and
       that won't overflow a digit. */
```